# Click report using Data extension fields

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, dataextensions

How would I go about pulling a click report leveraging fields that are in my data extension?

Currently we are pulling the DE from SF (no connector) - the click report I receive only has subscriber key and email.

I need to marry that back to my entire DE - 15 columns of data. (FN, LN, etc)
I have been using a vlookup - but its very manual.

is writing back to the DE the best route?

Answer (score 0):

You have to either use an alias tag within the link or use the impression region Ampscript function